# PLSQL code - Error 00103

Tags: function, plsql, package

I need you expertise on the following:-

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE USERS_LOGIN AS 
    FUNCTION LOG_IN(V_USERNAME IN USERS.USERNAME%TYPE,
                    V_PASSWORD IN USERS.PASSWORD%TYPE)
      RETURN VARCHAR2;
 END USERS_LOGIN;

 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY USERS_LOGIN AS  
    FUNCTION LOG_IN(V_USERNAME IN USERS.USERNAME%TYPE,
                    V_PASSWORD IN USERS.PASSWORD%TYPE)
      RETURN VARCHAR2 
    IS 
      LOGGED_IN VARCHAR2 := 'USER SUCCESSFULLY LOGGED IN';

      BEGIN 
        UPDATE USERS
          SET USER_ID  = USER_ID.NEXTVAL
          WHERE USERNAME = V_USERNAME AND
                PASSWORD = V_PASSWORD;    
        RETURN LOGGED_IN; 
      END;
```

I am getting error

```
Errors: check compiler log
11/4           PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting
                          one of the following:
begin end function pragma procedure
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you need END statements for the function LOG_IN and for the package body. Add the following as the last lines in the file:

```
  END LOG_IN;
END USERS_LOGIN;
```

In addition, the declaration for `LOGGED_IN` needs a length. Try it as:

```
LOGGED_IN  VARCHAR2(100) := 'USER SUCCESSFULLY LOGGED IN';
```

Share and enjoy.